# Replace word of a function with array

Tags: php, regex, word-boundary

I need to delete some words within a sentence, but I want the word to be deleted to match completely ...

This is my code:

```
<?php
function Clean ($text) {
 $array = array(
  'goo' => '',
  'guu' => '',
 );
 return strtr($text, $array);
}

$OldText = "goo guu mygoo myguu gooyou guuyou";

$NewText = Clean($OldText);

echo $NewText;
?>
```

**I want this:** mygoo myguu gooyou guuyou

**PHP returns:** my my you you

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You want to look at `preg_replace()`, so you don't delete the word if your string is just part of the word.

Comment: @Rizier123 I have been reading that topic for 1 hour, but I can not integrate it into the function I already have. Could you help me with some code to integrate it without changing much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` with word boundaries and you won't get partial matches:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s*\b(goo|guu)\b\s*/', '', $OldText);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/731588

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! It does not fit my current code but it serves as a basis to fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

**This is my complete solution, I hope someone else will serve you!**

```
<?php
function Clean ($text) {
 $array = array(
  '/\s*\b(goo)\b\s*/',
  '/\s*\b(guu)\b\s*/',
 );
 return preg_replace($array,'', $text);
}

$OldText = "goo guu mygoo myguu gooyou guuyou";

echo Clean($OldText);
?>
```

Comment: Oh, just use `'/\s*\b(?:guu|goo)\b\s*/'` or even better is `'/\s*\bg(?:oo|uu)\b\s*/'` instead of `$array` inside `preg_replace`.